# Execute stored procedure in EF Core returning int from JOIN. blazor(client-side)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-blazor

How can I get int value in EF Core returned from a stored procedure in SQL Server?

```
--Two tables, Employee and AspNetUsers--
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GetIdEmployeeByUserName
     (@username varchar(100), @idemployee int output)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @idemployee = (SELECT e.Id 
                          FROM Employee e
                          JOIN AspNetUsers a ON e.IdUser = a.Id
                          WHERE a.Email = @username)

END

--Executing in database--
DECLARE @idemp INT;
EXEC SP_GetIdEmployeeByUserName 'someinsertedemail@gmail.com', @idemp output
SELECT @idemp;
```

Returning the correct `Employee.Id` in SQL Server tests

```
idemp `Id = 40`
```

Now in Blazor (client-side) controller I'm trying to execute the stored procedure.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getbyname")]
public int GetByName([FromQuery] string username)
{
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                SqlParameter paramUsername = new SqlParameter("@username", username);

                var paramOut = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@idemp",
                    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
                    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
                };

                var result = _context
                    .Employee.FromSqlRaw
                    ($"EXEC SP_GetIdFuncByUserName @username, @idemp OUTPUT", paramUsername, paramOut)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                Console.WriteLine("result = >>>>>>>>> " + result);

                return result.Id;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ex -> " + ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I get this exception:

> FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it.
>   Consider calling `AsEnumerable` after the FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated method to perform the composition on the client side.

If try

```
var result = _context
                .Database.ExecuteSqlRaw
                ($"EXEC SP_GetIdFuncByUserName @username, @idemp OUTPUT", paramUsername, paramOut);
```

it always returns -1 because none lines were affected.

I see lot things but without success... Thanks in advance

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand if obsolete
```

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client
- https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17558
- [Include with FromSqlRaw and stored procedure in EF Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381530/include-with-fromsqlraw-and-stored-procedure-in-ef-core-3-1)
- [How to call a stored procedure in EF Core 3.0 via FromSqlRaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207182/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-in-ef-core-3-0-via-fromsqlraw)
- [EF core 3.1 can not run complex raw sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59876036/ef-core-3-1-can-not-run-complex-raw-sql-query)
- https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/stored-procedure-output-parameters/

Comment: have you tried `FromSqlRaw?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have non-composable SQL. The point is that Entity Framework will write something like

```
SELECT [Generated Column Names] FROM 
(
    @YOURQUERY
)
```

It does this to determine a format to be able to materialize the (nested) results, page them, and so on.

It cannot do compose this query if you don't select anything from your stored procedure. It doesn't return a resultset anyway, so you also won't be able to select from `dbContext.Employee`. That'll be two different queries. One to obtain the ID, which you already had:

```
var result = _context
            .Database.ExecuteSqlRaw
            ($"EXEC SP_GetIdFuncByUserName @username, @count OUTPUT", paramUsername, paramOut);
```

This does indeed return -1, because you have an error in your query. You provide a parameter named `@count` but a configured parameter named `@idemp`.

So make sure you properly pass the parameter:

```
var result = _context
                .Database.ExecuteSqlRaw
                ($"EXEC SP_GetIdFuncByUserName @username, @idemp OUTPUT", paramUsername, paramOut);
```

Then query using the ID parameter:

```
var employeeId = paramOut.Value;
var employee = _context.Employee.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == employeeId);
```

Comment: You are right. @count was only a copy/paste wrong. paramOut.Value; save me.